# Column sizing is not working in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, responsive, col

I am trying to make the form input fill the screen's width on small devices. But it is not working. It does work properly on bigger screens but not on phones when it should be responsive.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1 class="text-center" style="margin-top:100px;color:White;font-size:40pt;">Site in constructie</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-0 col-md-3"></div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                <form id="subscribeForLaunch" class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);" placeholder="Email" />
                    <button class="btn btn-info">Submit!</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-0 col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand what the question/issue is. The form input is full width on sm screens: https://www.codeply.com/go/dxui9n2nwa Also, there is no `col-0` class in Bootstrap.

Comment: @Zim the idea is that I want the input group to be centered and if it is viewed on a phone I would like it to be full width of the screen

Comment: That's exactly how it works right now. Did you look at the codeply?

Answer (score 0):

col-0 is not a valid class in Bootstrap as you can see in the documentation:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1 class="text-center" style="margin-top:100px;color:White;font-size:40pt;">Site in constructie</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"></div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <form id="subscribeForLaunch" class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" style="background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);" placeholder="Email" />
                <button class="btn btn-info">Submit!</button>
            </form>
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I did check before the documentation and col-* is a valid class [image: as you can see in this image]